# Merging master branch to another Git branch doesn't delete the files within branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

So, I started using Git just a couple of weeks back and facing a problem for which I can't seem to find a proper answer. The problem is quite simple, actually.

1. At the start of the release, we had a master, and that's it.
2. There were 3 branches created off of master, let's say X, Y and Z.
3. There were about 50 files deleted from X, and pushed back to master like 3 days ago.
4. Master correctly shows that those 50 files were deleted.
5. There was frequent interbranch merges between Y and Z for the last 3 days.
6. In an attempt to get all the changes together, I first update Y with all the changes in Z, and finally tried to 'Merge' the changes from X into Y hoping that would delete the files in my current branch (Y) that were originally deleted in X and later pushed into Master.

However, the merge doesn't delete the files, and I still have them all in Y. However, when I go the commit logs in SourceTree, I can clearly see the changeset where the 50 files got removed. Doesn't merge delete the files?

Comment: Please show the steps that you took the delete the files from X in the first place, and show what steps you're taking to merge.

Comment: well, these are c# files and proj files. So they were basically removed from project - and the corresponding deletes were pushed in normally within sourcetree. I can verify that X and Master are identical at this point. When I select "Merge Master into current branch" when I am at Y, it merges fine - doesn't show merge conflict that pertains to these deletes - and those files are still there. Does that help?

Comment: What gives;
git checkout Y;
git checkout -- .

Comment: How were these files modified in the Y branch? Were they removed and added back again?

Comment: It's just a guess but you could try to rebase Y instead of merging Z into it. That doesn't answer the question but maybe it will work as expected.

Comment: Are there commits in Y or Z deleting and then re-adding the files?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a caching problem. You had all the files in Y but then deleted them in X. For whatever reason, file additions and deletions tend to do weird stuff like this.

I'd try doing a loop over each file that you wanted to delete and remove it from the cache with

`git rm --cached <file>`

Heres a ruby script that will probably do it for you assuming you are on branch Y (not tested):

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

diff = `git diff --name-status X` #this will give you the name and status as (A, M, D, etc.)

# The output will look like this:
# A \t added_file
# D \t deleted_file
# M \t modified_file
# etc.

diff = diff.split #splits on new lines
deleted_files = diff.map do |entry|
  status_name_pair = entry.split('\t')
  return status_name_pair.last if status_name_pair.first == 'D'
end

deleted_files.each do |filename|
  `git rm --cached #{filename}`
end
```

Or if all your deleted files are in one directory you can just do:

```
git rm --cached <dir>
```